# matplotllib.pyplot axis definition

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

just a basic question regarding the functionality of the plt.axis definition or the plt functionality itself -

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[...]
plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 60])
[...]
```

Question: I can define axis before I start to work with the plot itself. I do not have to initiate a plt object or something equal. Seem from a technical perspective - do I initiate a plt object by defining the axis? Or how does it work? I'm a bit confused, since I tought an object should be initiated first before you do the "set" and "get" things...

Comment: Please review [Matplotlib Application Interfaces (APIs)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html). _The explicit "Axes" interface_, and _The implicit "pyplot" interface_. The `pyplot` module shadows most of the `Axes` plotting methods to give the equivalent of the [above](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface), **where the creation of the Figure and Axes is done for the user**.

Comment: Matplotlib does some stuff behind the scenes, to make things work more automatically for new or casual users.  There are many ways to obtain as similar result. However, you need to take into account that matplotlib behaves a bit different depending on the environment used, especially whether it is run interactive or as part of a standalone program. `plt.axis()`is just a convenience function, which can be safely replaced by more direct functions, e.g by `plt.xlim(...)` and `plt.ylim(...)`, or `ax.set_xlim(...)` and `ax.set_ylim(...)`

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help and explanations! :)